# Making pip working under python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I used `easy install` with Python 2.7 and now try to update to Python 3.4 but the pip is not very clear.

My OS is `Windows 7 - 64Bits` and I do not have administrator rights. For the moment I enter in a terminal:

```
C:\Users\bc50414\Documents>pip install Pyside
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\python.exe"" "C:\PF86\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe" install Pyside'
```

Where pip is just an alias for `doskey pip=C:\PF86\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe $*`. Apparently there is a problem with spaces, so using this solution (`python3=C:\PF86\Python34\python.exe $*`):

```
C:\Users\bc50414\Documents>python3 -m pip install Pyside
Downloading/unpacking Pyside
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Pyside
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Pyside
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\bc50414\pip\pip.log
```

Still fails ... the log is:

```
C:\PF86\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py run on 02/02/15 09:14:35
Downloading/unpacking Pyside
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/Pyside/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Pyside/: timed out
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/Pyside/ when looking for download links for Pyside
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

I guess it is a problem of Firewall/proxy since I am in a firm using this...so I tried this:

```
C:\Users\bc50414\Documents>python3 -m pip install --proxy="XXXXXmyproxyXXXXX" Pyside
Downloading/unpacking Pyside
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Pyside
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Pyside
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\bc50414\pip\pip.log
```

I really do not know hopw to solve this problem and afraid I am stuck with a lot of code in Python and pacakge I **can't** reach ...

Comment: `PySide` is written with a capital P and a capital S; not `Pyside` (your second error indicates there's a problem with the name: "No distributions at all found for Pyside").

Comment: I have the same problem with or without Capital ... :(

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip should be all you need. If your distro disabled pip by default (e.g. ubuntu if memory serves me right) you'd need to install that additional  package and frankly you're on your own

Comment: Also, if you don't have admin rights and python is installed system-wide, please use `virtualenv`

Comment: A system-wide install in Program Files must have been done by someone else with admin rights, and admin rights are required to modify the install by adding anything to PF/python34/Lib/site-packages.  Ask that person to make the change. The situation is a bit different when Python is installed elsewhere.

Comment: Yes someone installed python, but then I just used alias and put libraries in another places (and loading them with a special script). Tje story is that before the binaries for Windows were in `.exe` and now I must use pip since the extension is `.whl`. It is **very** impossible to make the change on admin rights, but I think this is not the primary issue of the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

PIP should already be included with Python 3.x
Open a command prompt in windows.
and type pip

you can open a command prompt by pressing windows button then type cmd in search for programs.

It should also be installed in accessories folder from your windows start button.